# Why are images almost always wrapped in links?

Tags: support, images

This question has been bugging me for a while now.

Images in posts are almost always wrapped in hyperlinks to the image file, like this:

```
[![alt text][1]][1]
```

And I don't know why. Is there a benefit to doing this?

Comment: [It was a feature implemented in July 2015](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151793/support-showing-image-in-original-size-in-overlay/261182#261182)

Comment: Programmers have nice big monitors.  I can't read the screenshot of their text editor on my laptop, so I click and zoom :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Because that's what automatically happens when you upload an image.

This way, the site can scale down an image when displaying it in a Q/A, while allowing you to open it to view in in its full glory.

All that, without anyone having to do any manual linking to differently scaled images.

Comment: Or having to (imagine the horror) right-click and open image in another tab.

Comment: @zaq of course, you can't do that in all browsers…

Comment: @zaq what is this "right click" that you speak of?

Comment: @StevenPenny legends say that it can be used by left-clicking while holding ctrl…

Comment: @StephenLeppik middle click

Comment: @StephenLeppik What is this "ctrl" that you speak of?

Comment: @CJDennis I'm pretty sure that almost all keyboards have a control key…

Comment: @StephenLeppik I was thinking about Mac keyboards but you're right, they do have them, it's just that you need to press Command instead.

Comment: There are legends about keyboards that have no backspace button, because their users make no mistakes (like that joke about philosophers that resign from erasers)

Comment: @StephenLeppik My smartphone and tablet would like a word with you, they seem to be lacking those control and click elements you speak of.

Comment: @9ilsdx9rvj0lo I think we call those "typewriters".